# Linear regresion for multiple time series

Tags: python, time-series, linear-regression

I have some data with this shape:

```
Key     Date     Value
key1    1/1/22   0,10
key1    2/1/22   0,12
key1    3/1/22   0,11
key1    ...

key2    1/1/22   1,30
key2    2/1/22   2,01
key2    3/1/22   1,71
key2    ...

key3    ...
```

SO basically, multiple timeseries (identified by Key) in only one pandas array.

Is there a way with some Python library to do a linear regresion and obtain something like:

```
Key     Slope    Intercept   Error
key1    ...
key2    ...
key3    ...
```

I know I can do it series by series, but my question is really, do I have to get the list of all unique keys, and then loop on all the possible keys, and for each, extract the [Date] and [Value] arrays for that particular serie, compute the slope/intercept/error... and iteratively create the resulting table, key by key? Or is there some library that can work with multiple series in one array and understand it is several series?